# is "the start date of the block to adding grades" correct?

Tags: phrase-request

I need a description of the column in the database that says that the ABC_date database column contains the date from which there is a block that prevents users from adding grades

is

*"the start date of the block to adding grades"*

correct?

Comment: What is an _ABC_date_? You should use a more understandable example, instead of cloaking your question in vagueness.

Comment: It is a database column

Comment: Is that really what you call it in your database?

Comment: no, but for security reason i cannot put the exact name here, anyway it is not in english so there is no point

Comment: Suit yourself. But you've made this a more difficult question to understand and therefore answer. Moreover, I find it hard to believe that "security reasons" prevent you from using a more meaningful synonym instead of such a vague generic name.

Comment: as I said the name is in foreign language if I could find a suitable expression for the column name I wouldn't ask the question

Answer (score 1):

So-called *cutoff dates* are often ambiguous: are they the last day when something is possible, or the first day when it is no longer possible?

It is common to find the phrase *on or after which* rather than *from which* in contexts where the speaker wishes to be very clear about when something commences.

This is *the date on or after which* the student may no longer add grades.

**This is the date on or after which the student is blocked from adding grades.**

**on or after** is a natural language way of expressing the idea of `>=` ("greater than or equal to") in calendar contexts.

*if today >= BlockDate then StudentCanAddGrades = false*

OR

*bool StudentCanAddGrades = (today < BlockDate)*

Edit: You can also express this idea without recourse to *on or after*:

**This is the date *on which* the block goes into effect, preventing students from adding grades.**

Comment: what I need is a description of the column, because I am adding column comments to the database, could you incorporate the word block or lock to this description so it is correct in English, as it is important to mention the block, I would be very grateful

Comment: See my edit for an alternative version using the word **block**.

Comment: "prevented" and "blocked" are synonyms.

Comment: @TRomano - I initially thought the O.P.'s use of the word _block_ referred to a block of time.

Comment: @J.R. "block to adding grades" was not immediately clear, true, but "to" was the clue, and then "prevents" sealed the deal.